# Expand columns of matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix "a" like the following:

```
a<-rbind(c("a1","ost1;ost2;ost3","utr;body;pro"),
      c("a2","idh1;idh2","pro;body"),
      c("a3","dnm1","body"))
>a
     [,1] [,2]             [,3]          
[1,] "a1" "ost1;ost2;ost3" "utr;body;pro"
[2,] "a2" "idh1;idh2"      "pro;body"    
[3,] "a3" "dnm1"           "body"
```

I want to get a matrix "b" like this

```
     [,1] [,2]   [,3]  
[1,] "a1" "ost1" "utr" 
[2,] "a1" "ost2" "body"
[3,] "a1" "ost3" "pro" 
[4,] "a2" "idh1" "pro" 
[5,] "a2" "idh2" "body"
[6,] "a3" "dnm1" "body"
```

OK, get it:

```
b<-do.call(rbind, (apply(a, 1, function(x) {do.call(cbind, strsplit(x,";"))})))
```

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: `do.call` is almost like magic :-) . Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution, without the unnecessary parentheses:

```
do.call(rbind, apply(a, 1, function(x) do.call(cbind, strsplit(x, ";"))))
```

This also works:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(apply(a, 1, strsplit, ';'), do.call, what = cbind))
```

Not that there is anything wrong with using anonymous functions (`function(x){...}`), but some people find it more "elegant" without any.